# Insert two arrays in database

Tags: php, html, arrays, database, insert

basically i am trying to imput two arrays in the database but i can't seem to actually get them in the right tables.

here is the code for the php function:

```
$numecap1 = $_POST['numecap'];
$contentcap1 = $_POST['contentcap'];
$numecap = implode(" ", $numecap1);
$contentcap = implode(" ", $contentcap1);   
$count_name = count($_POST['numecap']);
for($i=0;$i<$count_name ;$i++){
$_numecap  = mysqli_escape_string($con,$numecap[$i]);
$_contentcap  = mysqli_escape_string($con, $contentcap[$i]);

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO `".$prefix."".$titlu."`(numecap, contentcap) VALUES ('$numecap', '$contentcap')";}
```

and here is the html form (note: the java script adds how many text labales i need):

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Nume table <input type="text" name="table"><br>
    Autor <input type="text" name="autor"><br>
    Nrcap <input type="text" name="cap"><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="addInput()"/>

        <span id="responce"></span>
        <script>
            var boxName2 = 0;
            var boxName = 0;
            function addInput()
            {
                 var boxName="numecap"; 
            document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<br/>Nume cap<input type="text"  name="'+boxName+'[]" "  /><br/>';
                 var boxName2="contentcap"; 
            document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<br/>Continut cap<input type="text"  name="'+boxName2+'[]" "  /><br/>';


            }
        </script>   
    <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>
</form>
```

If someone can help, itll be hghly appreciated, since i am desperate!

Comment: So what problem are you actually having? Are you getting errors?  Have you dumped out the query that is created and tried to run it directly against the database? Where do you actually try to query the database?

Comment: for example if the array numecap has 3 elements, it insert all of them in one cell, i need them in diffrent table cells

Comment: what is the `$prefix` and the `$titlu` variables?

Comment: Well, then you need to make your query of the format `INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES ('value1a', 'value1b'), ('value2a', 'value2b'), ...`

Comment: $prefix $titlu create a specific database name.

Comment: Yeah i thought that may have been problem, but it wasn't, see my answer for what may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your $sql to this:

```
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO `".$prefix."".$titlu."`(numecap, contentcap) VALUES ('$numecap[$i]', '$contentcap[$i]')";
```

because that way, you create a new row, insert only one value. create a new row, insert next value. And so on.

Your for loop should look like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<$count_name ;$i++){
$_numecap  = mysqli_escape_string($con,$numecap[$i]);
$_contentcap  = mysqli_escape_string($con, $contentcap[$i]);

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO `".$prefix."".$titlu."`(numecap, contentcap) VALUES ('$_numecap', '$_contentcap')";

mysqli_query($c, $sql3);
}
```

Comment: or you can simply use the variables you create in the for loop: `$_numecap` and `$_contentcap` because they appear to be unused

Comment: I did so, and teh table is empty.

Comment: do you actually execute the query? `mysqli_query($c, $sql3);` within the for loop?

Comment: It seems like now the 2nd, 4th, 6th etc rows of the table are always empty, nothing get insert in them.

Comment: comment out the `mysqli_query` and below it type `var_dump($_numecap)` copy and paste the result here

Comment: e.g. if there are 3 numecap labels with the values 1, 3, 6 this is what it inserts: string(1) "1" string(1) " " string(1) "3"

Comment: try `var_dump($numecap)` to see if the main array contains the values you expect it to.

Comment: I fixed it! The thing was at the impldoe function where i used space as a separator and it counted as a value, anyways tyvm

Answer (score 0):

Perhpas you should look into the seralize and unseralize function which is available in PHP, this will assist you in inserting information into the database in the form of an Array!

```
$Array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$Array_2 = array(1,43985);

$Array = seralize($Array);
$Array_2 = seralize($Array_2);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php